# Join table with null values and sort

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have problem about joining table on SQL Server.
I have 1 table and I want to perform self join. Here's how my table look like

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Null | Null | A | B |
| Null | Null | A | B |
| AA | BB | Null | Null |
| AA | BB | Null | Null |

The result I want is :

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | BB | A | B |
| AA | BB | A | B |

I've tried `FULL OUTER JOIN` , `UNION` and `ORDER BY` but I don't get what I want.

Your answer will be so helpful. Thank you.

Comment: How do you map row AA, BB with first row ? What is your mapping criteria ?

Comment: @DaleK I've tried `SELECT A.Column A, A.Column B, A.Column C, A.Column D FROM MyTable A FULL OUTER JOIN MyTable B ON LEFT(A.ColumnA,1) = B.ColumnC ORDER BY A.Column A` .

Comment: @VenkataramanR My Mapping is only from `LEFT(ColumnA,1)` and `ColumnC`

Comment: @Arya: But then you'd get four result rows. Row 3 matches both rows 1 and 2, and row 4, too, matches both these rows. 2 x 2 = 4. So your mapping rule is incomplete. Please be precise on how to match rows. What rule do you want to apply exactly in order to end up with two result rows?. Make your example a little more complex, too. E.g. add a row `CC | DD || NULL || EE`. How would your result look like then and why? And can a row exist that matches itself (e.g. `NULL | FF | NULL | GG`)? What to do then? Think about this and tell us *precisely* what you want your query to do.

Comment: It is uncomon for tables to contain complete duplicates. Does your table really contain rows that are exactly the same and do you want to have those duplicates in your result? Or have you over-simplified your example? It may help to tell us what your real table contains, so we may understand better what you want to achieve. Maybe even you are trying to do something in SQL here that you should better do in your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one method you can try, as you have no join key so you can use row_number()

```
with cte as
(select columnA,ColumnB, 
row_number() over(order by columnA) rn1
from table_name where columnA is not null and ColumnB is not null
), cte1 as
(select columnC,ColumnD, 
row_number() over(order by columnC) rn2
from table_name where columnC is not null and ColumnD is not null
) select columnA,ColumnB,columnC,ColumnD from cte join cte1 on rn1=rn2
```

Comment: Hi @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin: If column_B value is NULL, BB, NULL, BB then this query isn't work properly.

Comment: @RahulBiswas I considered only the sample data

Comment: Hi @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Yes, you're right, I have no joining keys.  Thank you so much for your answer. It meets my need !

Answer (score 1):

You can go for ROW_NUMBER() function and assign row numbers and map the columns accordingly.

```sql
declare @table table(ColumnA    char(2), ColumnB    char(2), ColumnC    char(2), ColumnD char(2))

insert into @table
values
(Null,  Null,   'A','B')
,(Null, Null,   'A','B')
,('AA', 'BB',   Null,   Null)
,('AA', 'BB',   Null,   Null)

select a.ColumnA, a.ColumnB,b.ColumnC, b.ColumnD from 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by columnA) as rnk FROM @table  WHERE ColumnA is not null) as a
left outer join (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by columnC) as rnk FROM @table WHERE ColumnC IS NOT NULL) AS b
on left(a.columnA,1) = b.columnc and a.rnk = b.rnk
where a.columnA is not null and a.ColumnB is not null and b.ColumnC is not null and b.ColumnD is not null
```

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | BB | A | B |
| AA | BB | A | B |